# Local Roles for ATBTreeFolder vs ATFolder

Tags: plone, archetypes

I have a Plone site that is upgraded from Plone 3.3.5 to 4.0.7. From ZMI, I find there are 2 kinds of folders: ATBTreeFolder and ATFolder. With ATBTreeFolder, I can assign Local Roles in Security tab. With ATFolder, there is no such setting interface.

After I read http://collective-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security/local_roles.html and http://encolpe.wordpress.com/2010/02/08/add-a-new-role-in-the-sharing-tab-for-plone-3 ,  plone.app.workflow seems the right way to go. However, before writing my sharing.xml, should I "migrate" ATBTreeFolder to ATFolder or remove previous Local Roles setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should migrate from ATBTreeFolder to ATFolder, because in Plone4  Large Folders and Folders have been merged.

More:

- http://plone.org/products/plone/roadmap/191
- http://dev.plone.org/ticket/9316